# Change of Employer with 18B abs 1

Tags: resident-permit, work-permit

Hi I have  been working for past 3+ years with 18b abs 1. Now I got a new job offer with high salary more than the blue card salary limit. Do I need to get approval from Ausländerbehörde or just the information for them is enough.

Comment: For completeness, which country does your question relate to? Presumably Germany?